# Rails 3.2: Gem dependencies only for Sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, sidekiq

I have a Rails application which has a lot of code and dependencies. It has a web server component, a worker component (based on Sidekiq), and a database component.

I have some gems which must be in the workers, but I don't need them in the web servers. Nor do I want my controller or view code loaded in the Sidekiq worker.

Is there any way to tell Bundler  (via the Gemfile, I presume) to only include certain gems or classes in the workers, but not in the web server?

Answer (score 4):

If you add this to you Gemfile:

```
gem 'mygem', require: false
```

You can then conditionally require mygem within your initializers based on the environment.

Comment: This looks like a great approach - any reason to not do this (or a better approach) now in 2022? And would putting it in an initializer mean it gets loaded into the shared (Copy on write) memory if there are multiple processes? (relevant to puma and maybe sidekiq enterprise but not sidekiq/sidekiq pro which use threads but not processes - if I understand correctly)

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest solution is to create a worker group in your Gemfile:

```
group :worker do
  # These gems are only needed by the workers
  gem 'foo'
  gem 'bar'
end
```

These gems won't be loaded by default.

Then when initializing your workers call `Bundler.require(:worker)`

EDIT (in response to your comment):

Two perfectly acceptable options here,

a) Don't load rails environment in your workers.

I believe the right way to accomplish this is to invoke sidekiq with `sidekiq -r worker_environment.rb` where worker_environment.rb requires your dependencies and your worker files.

b) Configure your rails environment not to load the default gem group for your worker processes.

I'm not sure with Rails 3.2, but in Rails 4.x you will find a line in your config/application.rb `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)`. Rails.groups will typically be something like `[:default, :development]` or `[:default, :production]`. So you can add some logic to instead require only `:worker` if you are in a worker process (perhaps you can set an env var only for your worker processes in order to distinguish here).

Comment: I like this answer, but....Bundler already brings in my gems (I presume). Where is that done so that I could comment it out and call Bundler.require(:worker)  ?  Also, do I have to make this call in every worker, or is there some common place to do it?

Comment: Ah I didn't read your question carefully enough, sorry. I will make some edits...